# Error: expected an indented block

Tags: python, indentation

Can someone explain why I am getting this error?

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

datapath = r"C:\Users\matth\Downloads\MYD04_L2_v6.0_110E155E_045S010S.A2010_calcv2_dod_flg1.nc"
f = Dataset(datapath)

for i in range(0, 30):
    dod = f.variables['dod_modis_flg1'][i]
    dod[dod == 0] = np.nan

    def nan_if(arr, value):
        return np.where(arr == value, np.nan, arr)
    mean = np.nanmean([nan_if(dod, -9.99)])
    print(mean)
    #print(np.nanmax(dod))
    #print(np.nanmin([nan_if(dod, -9.99)]))

    dod_high = dod[(dod > mean) & (dod != 0)]
    anomalies = []
    for val in dod_high:
        if val > mean:
            #print(anomalies)

    dod_high_indices1 = np.where((dod > mean) & (dod != 0))
    dod_high_indices2 = np.array(np.where((dod > mean) & (dod != 0))).T
    anomalies_ind = []
    for ind in dod_high_indices2:
        anomalies_ind.append(ind)
        print(np.asarray(anomalies_ind))
```

OUTPUT:

```
%run "C:/Users/matth/dod_anomalies.py"
  File "C:\Users\matth\dod_anomalies.py", line 26
   dod_high_indices1 = np.where((dod > mean) & (dod != 0))
   ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

It seems to me that the indentation of my code is correct... for some reason, I keep on getting this error.

Comment: you should just uncomment `print(anomalies)`

Answer (score 3):

Python is expecting something after

```
if val > mean:
```

It ignores the commented block. If you have an empty if statement like that, just put in pass, so python knows that it is there.

```
if val>mean:
    #print(anomalies)
    pass
```

Comment: I feel pretty dumb now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

An `if` needs a body, and in

```
for val in dod_high:
    if val > mean:
        #print(anomalies)
```

a comment doesn't count. You could make the body `pass`, or comment out the `if` (or the whole loop), but in context, it seems like you might have more serious problems. Even uncommented, that `print` would only ever have printed `[]`.